# Can't access request parameters inside a middleware

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

I want to retrieve an `id` in the custom middleware that runs after following route: `/quiz/1/edit`. I expect, that the `$route` should contain `'id' => 1`, but it doesn't. Why is that?

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    dd($request->all()); // --> []
    . . .
}
```

The route declaration:

```
Route::resource('quiz', 'QuizzesController');
```

Comment: Can you show your route declaration?

Comment: @TheAlpha I've updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$request->route('quiz')` to get the params in route.

```
  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        dd($request->route('quiz'); // --> id
        . . .
    }
```

Comment: Good job! Congratulations!